# pushbullet service does not work

Tags: android

For my app I use pushbullet to send push messages to my device. On this device, I have an app, that should display this message. Therefore I use the pushbullet - API, described here: https://docs.pushbullet.com/extensions/messaging/guide/
So I add a service to my manifest file and implemented a class, that only should write a Log message.

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.stfgorbitzapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.pushbullet.android.permission.READ_MESSAGING_EXTENSION_DATA" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".SampleMessagingExtension"
        android:permission="com.pushbullet.android.permission.READ_MESSAGING_EXTENSION_DATA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.pushbullet.android.extension.MessagingExtension" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="protocolVersion"
            android:value="1" />
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

my basic activity, only showing "Hello World"

```
package com.example.stfgorbitzapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}
}
```

my class, that should be executed when receiving the intent:

```
package com.example.stfgorbitzapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.pushbullet.android.extension.MessagingExtension;

public class SampleMessagingExtension extends MessagingExtension{
private static final String TAG = "SampleMessagingExtension";
@Override

protected void onMessageReceived(final String conversationIden, final String message) {
Log.i(TAG, "Pushbullet MessagingExtension: onMessageReceived(" + conversationIden + ", " + message + ")");
}

@Override
protected void onConversationDismissed(final String conversationIden) {
Log.i(TAG, "Pushbullet MessagingExtension: onConversationDismissed(" + conversationIden + ")");
}

}
```

but when I send a push message, I could not read the Log message. Can onyone help me? Did I forget something? I.e. specific permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you need also Network state and Wifi permissions?
Pushbullet should use network to exchange notifications..

About the log: the priority is set to INFO level. Maybe do you filter them? 
Do you use Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Which is the code that create a SampleMessagingExtension object?

Comment: I thought it will be created by the service defined in the manifest?